# Flux Multiple Components Fire Action that dispatches simultaneously and fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm working with a fairly standard flux architecture setup in my React app.  The view has several instances (4 in this case) of the same component, which each displays a feed of data.  There's a single store that keeps track of the feed data.

In my ActionsScript I'm following a common pattern of dispatching an event for when data is requested, when it's received, or when an error occurs.

```
  getStories: (feedID) => {

      AppDispatcher.dispatch({
          actionType: StoryConstants.REQUEST_STORIES,
          feedID: feedID
      });

      StoryAPI
          .getStories(config)
          .then(response => {
              AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                  actionType: StoryConstants.RECEIVE_STORIES,
                  feedID: feedID,
                  stories: response.results,
                  metaData: response.meta
              });
          })
          .catch(response => {
              AppDispatcher.dispatch({
                  actionType: StoryConstants.RECEIVE_STORIES_ERROR,
                  feedID: feedID,
                  message: response.message
              });
          });
  }
```

Each feed component calls this action when it mounts.  And when it tries to fire that first dispatch for REQUEST_STORIES the app stops working and the components never render.  When I remove the dispatch the components render and load their data just fine.

I suspect that the dispatcher is erroring out because it's already dispatching.  But other than doing a hackey interval loop with a isDispatching check, I'm not sure of a good solution for this issue.